# How to evaluate a string to java script code when string contains a object and its properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have my code in string format like.

```
if(x.webGet){
    y.webGet="true";
}else{
    y.webGet = "false";
}
```

i want to eval this string in javascript.
x and y are the json object i have.
here the problem is that when i eval string it should able to read that objects and should able to update properties according to code.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "when i eval string" ??

Comment: Do you mean the `if .. else` statement is actually a string?

Comment: I have two objects like below 

1. x:{
    alcFile: ""
 webGet: "false"
 webPost: ""
 }
2. y:{
 calcFile: ""
 webGet: "false"
 webPost: ""
 }
and I have a string that contains a if else statements see below
let script:string  = “if(x.webGet){
    y.webGet="true";
}else{
    y.webGet = "false";
}”
Expected Result : When I run eval(script) so according to condition specified in above statements it should modify y object like  y.webGet="true" or     y.webGet="false"
And return y modified y object.

Comment: Don't use code as data, though it's possible. It's also possible to you to hit your head with a hammer. You don't want to do that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` to evaluate the string and run and update the object

```js
let x = {
  webGet: false
}

let y = {
  webGet: true
}


let str = 'if(x.webGet){y.webGet="true";}else{ y.webGet = "false";}'

eval(str);
console.log(y)
```

Comment: thanks for update i have few comments on this:  1 . its not checking x.webGet value it always going to else condition whether x.webGet contains string or not.   2. my y object contains multiple properties like "y: {webGet: "", webPost: "", calcFile: ""}" so instead of updating existing object property it adding extra webGet property in y object, something like this       webGet: "false"
y: {webGet: "", webPost: "", calcFile: ""} . ||  I hope you understand my concerns.